# Usage of 'learning_phase' in keras for tensorflow backend?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to train a resnet network using keras backend in tensorflow. The feed dictionary for each batch update is written as:

```
    feed_dict= {x:X_train[indices[start:end]], y:Y_train[indices[start:end]], keras.backend.learning_phase():1}
```

I am using keras backend (`keras.backend.set_session(sess)`) because the original resnet network is defined with keras. As the model contains dropout and batch_norm layers, it requires a learning phase to distinct between training and testing.

I observe that whenever I set `keras.backend.learning_phase():1`, the model train/test accuracy hardly increase above 10%. In contrast, if the learning phase is not set  i.e., the feed dictionary is defined as:

```
feed_dict= {x:X_train[indices[start:end]], y:Y_train[indices[start:end]]}
```

Then as expected, the model accuracy keeps in increasing with epochs in a standard way.

I would appreciate if someone clarifies **whether the use of learning phase is not necessary or if something else is wrong**. Keras 2.0 documentation seems to suggest using learning phase with dropout and batch_norm layers.

Comment: Its impossible to say what's wrong with only two lines of code, you should include more code. Also, why are you not just using model.fit?

Comment: @Ma The optimization step requires additional tweakings, which hinders the use of model.fit

Answer (score 0):

set the learning phase to 1 (training)

```
K.set_learning_phase(1)
```

Then you need to set the training=false for all batch normalization layers

```
if layer.name.startswith('bn'):
    layer.call(layer.input, training=False)
```